# set up, invite, and manage video conferencing sessions between users using ucma 3.0

Tags: ucma

How do set up, invite and manage video conference session using UCMA  3.0 and lync server 2010. Sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps :

1. Start Collaboration Platform
2. Create a LocalEndPoint.
3. Create a new Conversation using LocalEndPoint .
4. Schedule Conference on newly created Conversation .
5. Join and Escalate to conference.
6. Send Invitations to the Remote Participants.

If you explore SDK Samples you will get code for each step to follow. Let me know if you find difficulty to refer SDK Samples.